# Trying to save a LocalDateTime but the values saved to json are blank

Tags: android, json, android-studio, types, gson

In android studio I am trying to save the input of a calender view as a LocalDateTime as Json using internal storage, but I am facing a problem. I have the calenderView created and have it set so that it gets the date when you change it through the user interface as shown below.

```java
CalendarView dateInput = findViewById(R.id.calenderDate);
        dateInput.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                inputtedDate = LocalDate.of(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
            }
        });
```

Then I get the string from the textbox containing the user's inputted time before using the .of method to put them together as one DateTime.

```java
String timeString = timeInput.getText().toString();
LocalTime inputtedTime = LocalTime.parse(timeString);
LocalDateTime inputtedDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(inputtedDate, inputtedTime);
```

This is then saved to internal storage using Gson.

```java
public void WriteJsonToStorage(){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String json = gson.toJson(bookingToWrite);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
       
        fos = context.openFileOutput("SingleBooking.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(json.getBytes());        
    }
```

In the debugger I can see that this is what it picks up when I choose a date and write the time out manually as '14:56'

2023-12-14T14:56

But then when I check the file afterwards the dateTime I checked has nothing in it.

```json
{ 
  "bookingDateTime": {},
  "bookingName": 0,
  "peopleTotal": 5,
  "tableNumber": 0 
}
```

Is there a step that I am missing here so it can properly store the date and time in json?

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, but the point here is that Gson has currently no built-in adapter for `LocalDateTime` (which is probably the cause for or related to this issue). So you either have to write one yourself (as shown in the linked question), or use a third-party library which adds such an adapter to Gson, for example https://github.com/gkopff/gson-javatime-serialisers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the date and time in a specific pattern with locale you can use the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", 
Locale.getDefault());
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```